# Centos clear swap usage

Tags: centos6, swap

I got nagios monitoring and it is picking up high swap usage on a specific server. The user is using some application which triggers the high swap. Even after they quit the application, **top** still shows high swap used.

I've tried using **swapoff -a** and **swapon -a**. It doesn't reset the counter within **top**.

It seems like the only way to reset the counter is to reboot the server. Which is a pain.

[image]

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Reset the swap counter. Even after the process is killed, the high swap usage still remains until after a reboot. The high swap triggers the nagios alerts.

Comment: Can you fix Nagios so it doesn't trigger the false alerts? Clearly, the amount of used swap can't actually be greater than the total swap.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz nagios isn't wrong. top is showing higher swap used then the total amount of swap available. I've applied the latest Centos patches for this version.

Comment: It looks like a bug. Update your system.

Answer (score 6):

For the `swapoff` command to work, there should be enough free physical memory so that the swapped files can be moved. As far as I can see, your amount of swap usage is very high and there is no way the system can free it.

See the swapoff man page: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=swapoff&sektion=8

> ...Note that swapoff will fail and refuse to remove   a swap device 
>   if    there is insufficient VM (memory + remaining swap devices) to run
>   the  system...

There is certainly something wrong with your system which you should investigate. You can also try to run `swapoff` with the `-v` (for verbose) option to see if outputs more info.